# Bringing the xenbr0 interface up on XEN under Ubuntu 8.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, xen, ubuntu-8.04

I installed XEN on Ubuntu 8.04 using [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu-8.04-server-install-xen-from-ubuntu-repositories)
but after I reboot with the XEN kernel, I don't have xenbr0 device. I see that network-bridge script runs and it creates peth0 device, but not xenbr0.

I have a very basic IP setup, with a single static IP defined in /etc/network/interfaces. The only unusual thing is that my hosting (1&1) gave me a netmask 255.255.255.255, so I had to add the default gateway with this script:

```
/sbin/route add -host 10.255.255.1 dev eth0
/sbin/route add default gw 10.255.255.1
```

Everything else is plain vanilla Ubuntu 8.04.

Comment: Just a comment.. Xen is *back* in Ubuntu in 12.04, releasing this month. 8.04 will be EOL in 1 year, so perhaps consider 12.04 if you want this system to live much longer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using command brctl as shown below:
Create bridge named xenbr0

```
brctl addbr xenbr0
```

Add to that bridge interface like this

```
brctl addif peth0
brctl addif virtual_interface_of_your_xen_domain (e.g. vif2.0)
```

Now your bridge should be working.